Run processing without open QGIS - for specific project
In QGIS I have this process that starts with a double click without defining parameters.
I would like to start it without opening QGIS via a batch command.

ATTENTION: the process must be started for a specific .qgz project which contains the parameters within it.
My current bat:
C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.36.0\bin\python-qgis.bat" test_model_designer.py

My current py:
from qgis.core import QgsApplication, QgsProject
import sys

# Imposta il percorso del tuo installazione di QGIS
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath(r"C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.36.0\apps\qgis", True)
gui_flag = False
app = QgsApplication([], gui_flag)
app.initQgis()

# Aggiungi il percorso al framework Processing: è un PLUGIN di QGIS!
sys.path.append(r'C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.36.0\apps\qgis\python\plugins')

# Importa e inizializza il framework Processing
from processing.core.Processing import Processing
Processing.initialize()
import processing

# Percorso del progetto QGZ
project_path = r'C:\Users\opengis\Documents\MEGA\MEGAsync\qgis2web_test_qgz\test.qgz'

# Leggi il progetto QGZ senza interfaccia grafica
project = QgsProject.instance()
project.read(project_path)

# Esegui il task di esportazione del progetto
processing.run('qgis2web:exportProject', {'PROJECT': project_path})

app.exitQgis()

The py extracted from model designer:
"""
Model exported as python.
Name : modello
Group : 
With QGIS : 33600
"""

from qgis.core import QgsProcessing
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingAlgorithm
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback
import processing


class Modello(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):

    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
        pass

    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, model_feedback):
        # Use a multi-step feedback, so that individual child algorithm progress reports are adjusted for the
        # overall progress through the model
        feedback = QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback(1, model_feedback)
        results = {}
        outputs = {}

        # Export project
        alg_params = {
        }
        outputs['ExportProject'] = processing.run('qgis2web:exportProject', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
        return results

    def name(self):
        return 'modello'

    def displayName(self):
        return 'modello'

    def group(self):
        return ''

    def groupId(self):
        return ''

    def createInstance(self):
        return Modello()

